# Refreshing html via javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm trying to show a notifications counter updated upon javascript.

I have tried to use the following to refresh the html:

At the top of the page declaring the counter value (how many messages user has):

```
<?php
    $nc =  notificationCount($user_data['id']);
    $ng = $user_data['id'];
    if ($nc >= 1){
        $nstyle = 'style="display:block;"';
    } else {
        $nstyle = 'style="display:block;"';
    }
?>
```

Then the standard initial loading of the counter value that works properly:

```
<li id ="ndiv" class="nav-item pt8" <?php echo $nstyle; ?>><a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="showUser(<?php echo $ng;?>)"> 
    <i class="fa fa-bell f18 cr"></i><span id ="nc" class="f16 cr"><?php echo $nc;?></span></a>
</li>
```

In attempt to keep the counter refreshing every 5000 I tried the following, but it does not refresh despite the increase in value taking place.

```
<script>
    function checkNotification() {
        console.log(' each 5 second...');
        document.getElementById("nc").value =  "<?php echo $nc;?>";
    }
    var myVar = setInterval(checkNotification, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using server-side code for this in the first place?

Comment: "despite the increase in value taking place"  Where?  I'm not seeing anything that increases any value.

Comment: There is an ongoing increase every second in counter value in db

Comment: huh?  what database? you're aware that PHP runs server-side, right?  Once that page is loaded, that's it, the PHP is done.

Comment: $nc holds variable upon load. I can put it in a seperate page, and run js to get its value, what would that look like to pass value to html?

Comment: As others have stated, your PHP code will only be executed one time on the server than the results are returned to the client.  Any dyamic updates (without page refresh) need to be JavaScript AJAX calls to your PHP server to POST data and GET data.   These calls can then inject the data into the html page (using JavaScript) and this makes it dynamic.

Comment: @codingquestions You might want to look into using websockets.  Every 5 seconds is probably a little more frequent than I'd want for a polling/ajax script.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP page returns a result to the client. Once the page returns its result, it's done. You can't have a PHP page return a result every so often. But, what you can do is call out to a PHP page ([using AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)) that returns the notification count at regular intervals using `setInterval()`.

```js
let notifications = document.getElementById("notifications");

// This would be a function that calls a .php page to get
// the notification count returned. You could use AJAX 
// to make that call.
function simulateServerCode(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

let timer = setInterval(function(){
  notifications.textContent = simulateServerCode();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<div>You have <span id="notifications"></span> notifications.<div>
```

Comment: the counter is notifications counter

Comment: @codingquestions Please read the comment above that function. It's just a simulation of data you'd get back from making a call to a PHP file that would return your actual notification count. Instead of that line, you'd substitute a call to your PHP file that returns the actual notification count.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the server side for showing the notifications.

Try this:

JS:

```
notificationsCount = document.getElementById("notificationsCount");

numberOfNotification = 10; // example

showing = setInterval(function(){

      notificationsCount.textContent = numberOfNotificaton;

}, 5000);
```

HTML:

```
<h1>
    Number of notifications <h1 id="notificationsCount"></h1>
</h1>
```

Comment: I  just need to refresh my notifications! This does not help.

Comment: Yeah I understand that later, so I changed my answer